# invalid operands of types `double' and `int' to binary `operator%'

Tags: c++

When compiling gives the error invalid operands of types `double ' and` int ' to binary ` operator % '

```
int x, y, z;
float R;
cout <<"Ejercicio N 2"<<endl;
cout <<"De la expresion: R=(x^3*8MOD2DIVY/(3+x^2))/(8-z/7-y*11MOD2) suministrar el valor de tipo entero X,Y,Z"<<endl;
cout <<"Ingrese el valor de X: "; cin>> x;
cout <<"Ingrese el valor de Y: "; cin>> y;
cout <<"Ingrese el valor de Z: "; cin>> z;
R=(pow(x,3)*8%2/y/(3+pow(x,2)))/(8-z/7-y*11%2);
cout <<"La respuesta es: "<<R<<endl<<endl<<endl;
```

Comment: `pow(x,3)` is a floating point value. You can't use integer-based `%` with the result. Just do `x * x * x`. Or better yet, simplify it to 0, because `x * x * x * 8` will always be an even value, which modulo 2 is always going to be 0.

Comment: It's hard to see what are you trying to do when calculating R, perhaps you could break this down a little. My guess is  that you're maybe messing up with the operator precedence.

Answer (score 2):

There is no integer result overload of the `pow` function.

Hence the result is of floating point type, specifically the `double` type, and the C++ `%` operator only accepts integer argument.

You can use the `fmod` function for computing a remainder for floating point type arguments, or you can compute the integer power, e.g. as `x*x*x`.

---

Do note that if there *were* an integer result `pow`, then the sub-expression

```
pow(x,3)*8%2
```

… would always produce 0.

Can you see why?

Answer (score 1):

If you reduce the assignment of `R` down to this:

```
R = pow(x, 3) % 2;
```

Then it is more clear that the problem is `std::pow` returns a `double` and `2` is an `int`. One possible solution to make them the same type is to case the result of `std::pow`:

```
R = (int)pow(x, 3) % 2;
```

In your example, you do multiply `pow(x, 3)` by `8` but the result is still a double

Comment: This runs the risk of producing x^3-1 instead of x^3.

Comment: @Cheersandhth, Sure, he could just use `x * x * x` as you mentioned, but I don't even know what he is trying to calculate

Comment: You can use `static_cast<int>( pow(x, 3) + 0.5 )` for a more general power expression.

Comment: You can use many things, the problem is a double modulo integer two

Comment: No, that's not a problem at all. I updated my answer with info about that.